# RPi.GPIO Installation Error ;Exit status 1

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, iot, python-3.9, modulenotfounderror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oheJz.jpg)

I am trying installing the rpi.gpio in pycharm.. as can see in the image.. i am getting this error... someone please tell how resolve it.

Comment: Don't post image, copy and past your code or error msg, wrapped it with ``` so that it could format correctly as code block.

Comment: on python3 use `pip3` and not `pip`